# Can we use OSMnx to extract Street Networks from OSM in different years? Let me say 2000, 2005, 2010, and 2015

Tags: osmnx

I am using OSMnx to extract street networks, but unfortunately, I can't obtain different years of street networks from OpenStreetMap. Does anyone have tips for doing that, please? Thanks.

Comment: What specific information that exists in OpenStreetMap are you trying to retrieve for this? Does it exist on OSM?

Comment: @gboeing Thanks for your answer. I want to retrieve drivable, bikeable, and walkable street networks from OSM by using OSMnx. These networks surely exist on OSM. May you please give me some tips to retrieve these street networks using OSMnx? THANKS!

Comment: @gboeing, May you please give me some tips? Thanks!